# my web page container is getting smaller when i always click my modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

My problem is my web page container is getting smaller when i always click my modal and close it but i already try my modal in the other pages of my web there is no problem at all. Can someone help me with this problem. This is my code

```html
<div class='modal fade' id='".$row['id']."' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel'>
  <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        <form>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='recipient-name' class='control-label'>Name:</label>
            <label for='recipient-name' class='control-label' value='" .$row['id']. "'>" .$row['fname']." ".$row['mname']." " .$row['lname']. "</label>
          </div>
          <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='recipient-name' class='control-label'>Gender:</label>
            <label for='recipient-name' class='control-label'>".$row['gender']."</label>
          </div>
       </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I finally figure it out one of my js file has been repeated like this

```js
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fileinput.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
    <script>$('input[type=file]').bootstrapFileInput();</script>
    <script>$('.file-inputs').bootstrapFileInput();</script>
```

I just deleted the src="js/bootstrap.min.js" so it will not cause the problem.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to provide a helpful solution. Add in the related CSS or JS if possible, or give a better description of what you mean by your "page container getting smaller"

Comment: Well, immediately I see that you are including bootstrap and jquery _twice_ in your dependencies.